# compiler ignores explicitly-defined move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I'm trying to understand why the following code doesn't call my move-constructor. I compiled using gnu++11.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
  int value;
  public:
  Foo(int v){ value = v; }
  Foo(const Foo& g){ 
    value = g.value; 
    std::cout << "copy construct called\n"; 
  }
  Foo(Foo&& g){ 
    value = g.value; 
    std::cout << "move construct called\n"; 
  }
  int getValue() const{ return value; }
};

Foo operator+(const Foo& f, const Foo& g){
  Foo h(f.getValue() + g.getValue());
  return h;
}

void sayValue(const Foo& f){
  std::cout << f.getValue() << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  Foo f(5);
  sayValue(f + f);
  return 0;
}
```

Running the following code simply prints `10` instead of

```
move construct called
10
```

as I expect. The reason I expect that is because when I define the + binary operator for Foo's, returning Foo g should invoke the move constructor, if I understand correctly.

Is this because the compiler is simply optimizing by ignoring my move constructor define, or is it because one of my assumptions is flawed?

Comment: `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: Some things you might be interested in reading about: [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: okay, with that compile flag I got the expected message. Does this mean that *without* the compile flag, my compiler was using its own highly optimized version of a move constructor, rather than the one I explicitly defined?

Comment: @xdavidliu No, it just constructed the object where it needed to be in the first place, so there was no need to move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ there is a concept known as elision.

Elision permits the compiler to join the lifetime of various variables into one lifetime -- their existence is elided together.

It can elide a temporary being used to directly construct a value of the same type, or a named local variable being returned from a function in a simple `return x;` style statement.

The constructor to make it legal must exist, but the compiler need not invoke it.  Elision is permitted to occur even if the copy or move ctor would have side effects, hence the fact your print statement does not run.

So the compiler did not move -- it just constructed the object where it was going to go directly!  The value `h` was actually the actual return value of the `+`.

Had you done

```
Foo x = f+f;
```

The compiler could elide `h`, the return value of `+` and `x` into one object.

---

Two common cases that date back a while are NRVO and RVO (named return value optimization and return calue optimization), but they are just names for particular techniques that compilers do to elide.  The compiler is not forced to elide, but is permitted to.  In some cases, elision is difficult for the compiler to do (and IIRC in one case not permitted); in every such case, the move ctor can be called instead (or copy if no move exists).  An example is when you have two different local variables returned from a function; it makes it hard for compiler to elide both with the return value legally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo operator+(const Foo& f, const Foo& g){
    Foo h(f.getValue() + g.getValue());
    return h;
}
```

This invokes [NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and bypasses the need to use the move constructor to return the object.